# Is it possible to skip codeclimate analysis for changes to certain files

Tags: code-climate

Codeclimate analysis runs for every pull request that is raised. However, I would like it to skip the analysis when changes are done to files under the excluded folders.

Is it possible to configure such behaviour? The aim is to reduce the time taken for a change/fix to be merged. And for fixes that don't involve the code that needs to be analyzed, I would like the changes to be merged without waiting for the analysis to be over.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can exclude files or folders using `exclude_paths` in a `.codeclimate.yml` file.

Some samples:

```yaml
exclude_paths:
  - "**/build"
  - "**/node_modules/"
  - "**/generated/"
  - config/
  - db/
  - dist/
  - features/
  - "**/spec/"
  - "**/vendor/"
  - "**/*_test.go"
  - "**/*.d.ts"
  - "**/*.min.js"
  - "**/*.min.css"
  - "**/__tests__/"
  - "**/__mocks__/"
```

For details you can check [Excluding Files and Folders](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/excluding-files-and-folders)